# How can I position a UIColorWell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a UIColorWell into my storyboard, but it seems that you can't drag and drop a UIColorWell in the same way that you can with other elements like a UITextField.

So, what I did was generate the UIColorWell from within my view controller's .swift file.

Is there a way that I can attach the UIColorWell onto a UIView that I have drag and dropped into my storyboard?

Here is how I've tried to attach it, but when I run the simulator I don't see the color well showing up anywhere on the screen.

```
class TagSelectionViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var colorWell: UIColorWell!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var UIViewForColorWell: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addColorWell()
    }
    
    func addColorWell() {
        colorWell = UIColorWell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        self.view.addSubview(colorWell)
        colorWell.center = UIViewForColorWell.center
        colorWell.title = "Select Color"
        colorWell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(colorWellChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func colorWellChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = colorWell.selectedColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to add a UIColorWell into my storyboard, but it seems that you can't drag and drop a UIColorWell in the same way that you can with other elements like a UITextField.

**As of Xcode 14, this is no longer a problem!** You can now find `UIColorWell` in the interface builder.

[image]

Old Answer:

Actually, you can add it to the storyboard. It's just not in the list of views that you can choose from when you click the "+" button (maybe in the future?), so it's the same way as you add any other custom view that you have written.

Add a regular `UIView` to the desired position of the `UIColorWell`,

[image]

go to the identity inspector and set the class to `UIColorWell`:

[image]

You won't actually see any change on the storyboard, but if you run the app, you will see the color well:

[image]

Comment: We now get a UIColorWell in Storyboard and we can visually see it as well.

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong:

```
    self.view.addSubview(colorWell)
    colorWell.center = UIViewForColorWell.center
```

In the first place, if you are going to add the color well to `self.view`, then you must position it with respect to `self.view`. But you said you wanted to add it to UIViewForColorWell, so why did you not do that?

Second, setting the subview `center` to the superview `center` is never right, because they are in two completely different coordinate systems; the way to center one view inside another is to use autolayout, or set its center to the `midX`/`midY` of the superview's bounds.

Finally, make sure the sizing on your UIViewForColorWell (terrible name) is good.

So I would say, try this:

```
    UIViewForColorWell.addSubview(colorWell)
    let b = UIViewForColorWell.bounds
    colorWell.center = CGPoint(x:b.midX, y:b.midY)
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply. This is my first Xcode project, so I'm not familiar with everything just yet. The only reason I added the UIView(UIViewForColorWell) was just so that I could drag it around and position it on my view controller.